# Layout run failed when changing orientation of panels

Tags: extjs

After changing the orientation of the panels when I am trying to pin a docked window into a tab. I am getting this errror Layout Run failed.

Help apperetiated.

Comment: Check whether the width and height are set on panels. Usually, the layout cannot be calculated when there is no width and/or height to start with. I would guess that the width is set and the height is not or vice versa.

Comment: Please share your code so that we can get some idea.